# XPathExpression.evaluate using Node

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following XML (which I receive and so do not have control of):

```
<root>
   <elementA  ....>
       <elementB  ....>
            <nsx:elementC  ...>
```

At a point in my code I have the `Node - elementA`. What I am trying to do is get `elementC` ignoring the namespaces (the document was parsed with namespace aware = true because I want to be able to use `getLocalName` throughout my code.

I am using the following code:

```
Element elementA = ...;
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(<see below for xpath);
Node result = expression.evaluate(elementA, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Here are my results per tried XPath:

- "."  --> elementA
- "./*" --> elementB
- "./elementB" --> null
- "elementB" --> null

I don't get why if "./*" gives me `elementB`, "./elementB" gives me null.

Eventually, what I would like is something like: "./*:elementB/*:elementC"

Comment: I'm looking into my crystal ball here and am going to predict that your XML has a default namespace that you are ignoring.

Comment: have you tried ./*:elementB ?

Comment: @Carlos "./*:elementB" results in an exception: "Prefix must resolve to a namespace"

Comment: @Tomalak You are correct. Didn't notice. Is there an easy way to ignore? I have tried ```./*[local-name()=elementB]``` with no luck

Comment: Don't ever ignore namespaces. Every XPath engine has a way to declare and use them.